# Integral of $\tan(\ln(x+1))/x$

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I solve this integral?

$$\int{\frac{\tan(\ln(x+1))}{x}dx } $$

I tried substitution: $x+1 = e^t $,

$$\int{ \frac{e^t \cdot \tan(t)}{e^t -1 }dt} $$

and U-substitution: $u = \tan(t), \ v=\ln(e^t-1) $, but it doesn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that you need the antiderivative ? I doubt there is one even using special functions. Are you rather asked to compute a definite integral ?

Answer (score 1):

$|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$
$$\int\frac{e^t \tan t}{e^t-1}dt=\frac{1}{2}\int\tan t dt+\int(\frac{t}{2}+\frac{t}{e^t-1})\frac{ \tan t}{t}dt=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\cos t|+\int(\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}t^{2k} )( \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{2^{2k+2}(2^{2k+2}-1)B_{2k+2}}{(2k+2)!}t^{2k})dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln|\cos t|+\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{t^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\sum\limits_{v=0}^k (-1)^v\frac{2^{2v+2}(2^{2v+2}-1)B_{2v+2}B_{2k-2v}}{(2v+2)!(2k-2v)!}+C$$

Comment: +1 for creativity.A brute force Taylor-Maclaurin expansion is certainly a valid way to go,but it's hard to imagine a calculus instructor would encourage that method of solution. I think a closed form method would be more appropriate here,which is why most-myself included-didn't use it.

Comment: @mathemagician1234 : Thank you! But I have written this ("half-closed") because I think there is no closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Use parts and substitution. Let

Let u = ln(x+1)  and let dv = $\frac{1}{x}$ dx.
Then du= $sec^{2}$(In(x+1)) $\frac{1}{x+1}$dx and v = In x. So we get:

ln(x+1)In x - $\int{In(x) * sec^{2}(In(x+1)}$ dx

It looks like we have to apply parts several times,there's no quick way around this. Of course,you could cheat and use a computer algebra system like Mathematica, but otherwise sharpen your pencil.....lol

Comment: Why the capital "i"?

Comment: I think you mean $u=\tan(\ln(x+1))$, but this doesn't look very promising.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Use a substitution $u=\ln(x+1)$ so that $du=\frac{1}{x}\,dx$. Can you solve the rest of it from here?

*Edit:* Follow the other dude :)

Comment: Just a minute-that's not right. Isn't du= $\frac{1}{x+1}$*1 dx ??

Comment: Wait, $du=\frac1{x+1}dx$. (OP tried this substitution.)

Comment: @grand_chat DUH? lol

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahaha all of you are right :-P

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: Thanks :)

Comment: @grand_chat: :) Thanks